# Is this a reverse osmosis system?

Tags: plumbing, sink

I just purchased a home that appears to have a reverse osmosis system, but nothing comes out of the spigot, so I'm not sure if it is in fact R/O, if it's broken, etc.

Here's an album of the system in question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHH27.jpg -- it's the thin white tube that runs to the wall, but there's no filters that I can see. It just appears to run into a smallish box on the wall, then up to the spigot.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what's left of it anyway. My guess is that all of the filters were removed and the lines were just put together so you didn't ask, "Hey, what's this do?". -Nothing, they took everything except the kitchen sink.

[image: http://espwaterproducts.com/about-reverse-osmosis.htm]

[espwaterproducts.com/about-reverse-osmosis](http://espwaterproducts.com/about-reverse-osmosis.htm)

Comment: Is enough left that it's worth trying to replace the missing parts? Or would that be basically buying an entirely new system? If so, can I just remove the tube going to the drain and cap it with a brass fitting?

Comment: @Matt You'd need a *plug* for where that plastic elbow is and a 'sink hole cover' insert. You own a spigot; you'd need everything else. The original owners must be water freaks if they took it with them, or your water sucks. Keep the option open until you decide which.

Comment: @Matt There's basically nothing left of the system. Looks like you have the faucet, which is attached directly to the drain line. If the system once looked like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hwVSV.png), it now looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/094VX.png).